# Topological graph sorting java

Tags: java

I've got some problems with the topological sorting. It can find lops, but it counts some of the tasks (or "nodes" if you want to call it) several times. I think the problem is something with how I read or the Edge class, but I just can't see where it goes wrong. Any help would be really appreciated :)

```
enter code here
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Task {

    int id, time, staff;
    int depA, depB;
    String name;
    int eStart, lStart;
    Edge outEdge;
    int cntPredecessors;
    boolean visited;

    Task(int id, String name, int time, int staff)  {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.time = time;
    this.staff = staff;
    visited = false;
    }

    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }
    public String toString() {
    return name;
    }
}

class Edge {
    Task id, name, time, staff;
    Edge neste;
    Task fra, til;

    Edge(Task id) {
    this.id = id;
        }
}



class Input {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("enter a filename!");
        System.exit(1);
    } else if (args.length == 1) {
        String fil = args[0]+".txt";
        LesFraFil(fil);
        //  skrivUt();
        topSort();
    } else {
        System.out.println("too many parameters, try again...");
    }
    }

    static int antTask;
    static Task[] ids;
    static int tTid;
    static void LesFraFil(String fil) {

    int i = 0;
    int j;
    try {

        String lest;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(fil));
        Edge til;

        int counter = 0;
        antTask = in.nextInt();
        ids = new Task[antTask];
        System.out.println(antTask);
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {

        lest = in.nextLine();
        // hvis tom linje, så hopper den over
        if(lest.trim().length() == 0) continue;

        String split[] = lest.split("\\s+");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
        String act = split[1];
        int tid = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
        int staff = Integer.parseInt(split[3]);
        int depA = Integer.parseInt(split[4]);
        tTid += tid;
        ids[i] = new Task(id, act, tid, staff);
        j = 4;

        /*
         * Lesingen av inputen skal avbrytes når den leser 0.
         * j er den som holder på hvor langt vi er i split arrayet
         * når den møter på 0 
         */
        while(split[j].compareTo("0") != 0) {
            int tmp = Integer.parseInt(split[j])-1;

            //  System.out.println(tmp+1 + " Aktivitetens navn : " + act); //+ " tiden aktiviteten tar tid: " + tid + " avhengihet: " + split[j]);

            j++;

            if (ids[tmp] == null) {
            ids[tmp] = new Task(id, act, tid, staff);
            ids[tmp].visited = true;
            }
            ids[i].cntPredecessors++;
            if(ids[tmp].outEdge == null) {
            ids[tmp].outEdge = new Edge(ids[i]);
            } else {
            til = ids[tmp].outEdge;

            while(til.neste != null) {
                til = til.neste;
            }
            til.neste = new Edge(ids[i]);
            }
        }
        counter++;
        i++;
        }

        if (antTask == counter) {
        System.out.println("Lesinga gikk som planlagt av fil: " + fil);
        System.out.println("Total arbeidstid: " + tTid);// + antTask + " == " + counter );
        } else {
        System.out.println("Noe gikk galt avslutter!");
        System.out.println(antTask + " || " + counter);
        System.exit(2);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR!" + e.getMessage());
    }
    }


     static void skrivUt() {
    for (Task sort : ids) {
        System.out.print(sort.id + " " + sort.name);
        Edge til = sort.outEdge;
        while (til != null) {
        System.out.print(" " + til.id.id);
        til = til.neste;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
   }

    static void topSort() {
    LinkedList<Task> list = new LinkedList<Task>();
    ArrayList<Task> array = new ArrayList<Task>();
    Task temp;
    int count = 0;
    int totalTime = 0;

    // Legger taskene i lista
        for (Task t : ids) {
        if(t.cntPredecessors == 0) {
        list.add(t);
        totalTime += t.time;
        //  System.out.println(t);
        t.visited = true;
        }   
    }
    for (Task t : ids) {
        if(t.cntPredecessors == 1) {

        list.add(t);
        totalTime += t.time;
        //  System.out.println(t);
        t.visited = true;
        }
    }

    // går i evig løkke til lista er tom.
    while (!list.isEmpty()) {
        temp = list.pop(); // fjerner elementet fra lista
        array.add(temp); // legger inn i arraylisten
        count++;
        //    System.out.println(temp);
        for(Edge til = temp.outEdge; til!=null;til=til.neste) {
        til.id.cntPredecessors--;
        if(til.id.cntPredecessors==0) {
            list.add(til.id);
        }
        }
    }
    if(count < antTask) {
        System.out.println("A loop has been found. Terminating...");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Topological sort: " + Arrays.toString(array.toArray()));// den sorterte "arraylisten" 
    System.out.println("Total time spend: " + totalTime);
    }

} // End class Input
```

Here is an example of an input file

```
8

1   Build-walls     4 2       5       0
2   Build-roofs     6 4       1       0
3   Put-on-wallpapers   1 2       1       2       0
4   Put-on-tiles        1 3       2       0
5   Build-foundation    4 2       0
6   Make-floor          2 2       5       0
7   Put-carpet-floor    4 2       6       2       0
8   Move-in         4 4       3       7       0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this loop (inside `topSort()`):

```
for (Task t : ids) {
    if(t.cntPredecessors == 1) {

    list.add(t);
    totalTime += t.time;
    //  System.out.println(t);
    t.visited = true;
    }
}
```

You just need to remove it.

Reason: this loop adds to `list` nodes that have 1 incoming edge. Later (in the `while` loop), it is possible that for these nodes the `cntPredecessors` field will be decreased to 0 which will make them being pushed back onto `list`, thus counted twice.

In the future, please try to narrow down your code to something that contains less "noise", that is: the smallset (or nearly smallest) code that illustrates the problem. This will ease the understanding on potential answerers (not to mention that it may help you see the problem yourself).

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to remove it before, but then it only find loop and the return for topological search is only two nodes apperantly. That's the reason why I posted it all because I am not quite sure if the errors are when I read it, or when I sort it.

Comment: I think it should go something like 5 - 1 - 6 2 - 3 - 4 - 7 - 8